# Angular 4 : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular

Error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'myserviceURL' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Sample Code:

```
  let myHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  let username: string = 'admin';
  let password: string = 'admin';
  myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
  myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  var data={
        "username":userName,
        "password":Password,
  }

  return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: myHeaders })
  .subscribe(
  res =>{
    console.log(res);
  },
  err => {
    console.log("Error occured "+err.status);
  }
  );
```

Comment: How's the backend code? When you do a request, have you added `http://` at the start?

Comment: To you have access to the server? CORS is a server side setting so it won't be a client side problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your back-end is running on different port, Chrome, by default, will prevent Cross origin resource sharing. When you are developing app, you have to create proxy that will be ran within ng serve or npm start and he will recreate/forward all your api calls to specified address. Here's example:

//proxy.json

```
   {
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

What does this mean?
Any http request that is pointed towards `/api` will be rewritten to `http://localhost:8080`.

Also, you have to either change `npm start` property inside of `package.json` or change `ng serve` inside of `angular.json` so that proxy will be ran by default with command `ng serve/npm start`

//angular.json

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "yourapp:build",
        "proxyConfig": "proxy.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "yourapp:build:production"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is a server-side issue,
What you can do is: If you are using chrome, you can add chrome extension for CORS which will allow access to 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

it will work.

worked for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

when you are using 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' Please send the encoded data(Object) in this format.

```
    const data =
      'username=' +
      encodeURIComponent(userName) +
      '&password=' +
      Password +
      '&grant_type=password';
```